# Unity Editor - From BinaryWriter to Object or TextAsset

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

Is there any way to retrieve the file that a BinaryWriter creates and turn it into a TextAsset or Object?

I'm creating a custom editor for my project, it has an option to create a new binary file:
[image]

The field 'File' is for the user to drag an existing file, but the user can create a new one pressing the 'Create New File' button and ideally I would like the newly created file to be automatically placed in the field 'File'.

EDITED: As much as possible I would like to avoid saving the binary file to the resources folder and then load it and convert it to a TextAsset.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Save the new TextFile using BinaryWriter into the `Resources` Folder. (Create on in your Workspace, if there is none)

2.a) Get the File as TextAsset via

```
 TextAsset textFile = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("myTextFile"), typeof(TextAsset));
```

2.b) Alternatively, try this to load the recently-generated file:

```
AssetDatabase.ImportAsset(path); // Update/Reload File in Unity
TextAsset asset = Resources.Load("myTextFile");
```

3. Assign textFile to the public variable `File` in your Custom Editor script.

If you don't want a Resources Folder, try this:

[AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath.html)

Note: `AssetDatabase.Refresh()` updates Unity's file catalogue, so I was wrong with `ImportAsset`. See comments below.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer KYL3R. Not sure what exactly is "Test" in the Resources.Load. It seems it takes the path. So I passed the path that I use to create the file but that returns null (after casting it from Object to TextAsset). How AssetDatabase and Resources are related? Finally, if possible I would like to avoid creating those files in the Resources folder.

Comment: The AssetDatabase call updates the file inside Unity. So that it can be found as a TextAsset. 

You can use the [WWW](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) Class to load from disk (outside of Resources Folder) - but that won't give you a textAsset.


I added another possibe Solution "LoadAssetAtPath", see my answer.

Comment: Thanks a million KYL3R!! So at first I tried the way it appears in the Unity documentation but didn't work out, and then researching I found a slightly different way that did the trick - this is the magic line: Object o = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(path, (typeof(Object))) as Object;

Comment: Just a note to add, Unity takes some time to acknowledge the new asset, so I refresh the AssetDatabase (AssetDatabase.Refresh()) before use the LoadAssetAtPath and that worked perfectly :) Thanks again for your help KYL3R.

Comment: Thank you for reporting back @Cris. I'm glad you figured it out :)